# VBA / HTML / jQuery Chosen AutoComplete - Select in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vba, autocomplete

I'm trying to select a value in a list on a website using VBA in Excel.
It's not a "normal list", the website is using jQuery Chosen auto-complete (like this : [example](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/jquery-chosen.php) ).
It looks like this : 
[screenshot](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=756576jquerychosen.png) .

I tried a lot of things (like for usual lists), but only SendKeys worked and I would like to use a better method.

I saw on the "head" part of the HTML code that chosen.jquery.js is used on the page.

Here is the HTML code of the box :

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="texteFormulaire" style="width:600px;  " onblur="" onmousedown="" onclick="" onchange=""  >
<option value="0">---</option>
<option value="1">blabla</option>
<option value="2">blublu</option>
</select>
<script> 
  autoCompleteSelect.activerAutoCompletePourSelect("type");
</script>
```

If you have any idea, thanks a lot !
I don't know if I put all the information you may need, please don't hesitate to ask me for further informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found an answer.
Maybe it will help others :

```
Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy: Set CurrentWindow = IE.document.parentWindow
Call CurrentWindow.execScript("jQuery('#type').val('2');jQuery('#type').trigger('chosen:updated');")
```