# How do i click on a jQuery-autocomplete generated list via VBA?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vba, autocomplete

I'm trying to click on a list in a browser generated by jQuery/autocomplete through VBA.

I have tried using ".click" function, but it still wont click on the list. I also tried using "selectedindex" but it only returned error. I also tried "fireevent" with onchange. I got no error but it still didn't click on the list.

There are similar threads here:

[VBA / HTML / jQuery Chosen AutoComplete - Select in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649727/vba-html-jquery-chosen-autocomplete-select-in-a-list)

[How to fill in html autocomplete fields using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107030/how-to-fill-in-html-autocomplete-fields-using-vba)

But the solution provided did nothing. I'm still new to javascript, so maybe I did something wrong.

This is what i currently have:
[This is the textbox im trying to work on("Konto")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrVwx.png)

[The dropdownlist that appears when typing in the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhabL.png)

[A new dynamic element generates at the bottom of the code when the dropdownlist occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnVm6.png)

This is the code im currently working on:

```
Main.ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(12).Value = Sheets("Visma").Cells(2, 5).Value Main.ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(12).Focus
Set liste = Main.ie.document.getElementsByClassName("wicket-aa")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")
Do While liste.Length = 0: DoEvents: Loop
Debug.Print liste(0).innerHTML
liste(0).Click
```

I can't target the ID since they generate new IDs every new session.

When i run the code, [the input gets filled and the dropdownlist appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D11bh.png), but it wont click on that list. When i [print the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57EBc.png), it does indeed display the item i want to click on.But "liste(0).click" doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Here is the HTML-code for the textbox:

```
<div class="form-group costCentreElement">
    <label><a href="javascript:;" tabindex="0" id="id20">Konto</a></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control ccDimensionField" maxlength="12" onkeypress="return disableEnterKey(event)" value="" name="kontLinjer:1:konteringLinjePanel:konteringForm:kPanel:form:wmc:kbInputView:0:kbInput" id="id21" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Konto" onfocus="select();" tabindex="1">
```

I believe this is the code for autocomplete that genereates the dropdownlist when typing in the textbox:

```
<div class="wicket-aa-container" id="id21-autocomplete-container"     style="overflow: auto; position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width:  auto; left: 217px; top: 688px; display: none;">
    <div id="id21-autocomplete" class="wicket-aa">
        <ul>
            <li textvalue="4330">4330 - KARTONGER/ESKER</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the url? An example input value as well.

Comment: Hi Qharr,

Im sorry but the url only works on local connection. I will try to describe the situation better to my best effort. I will include an example input as requested. Thanks for taking your time, Qharr.